# Static Website Query CouchDB using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nosql, couchdb

I was wondering if it is possible for my HTML static website to query couchdb using AJAX and return the results without the use of other dynamic server side languages such as PHP, Python etc. The couchdb may well be hosted on another server / domain so it would have to be possible using JSONP.

The end goal would be efficetly to make a message board made purely in HTML, CSS and JS using a NOSQL database backend.

Comment: Why did you open this question twice?

Comment: Because you shat all over the other one because it wasn't specific enough

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is couchapp. CouchDB can host your static files, while you retrieve the data using AJAX. There are some great tools for keeping the structure of the application and to manage the deployment. Here is your starting reading point:

http://couchapp.org/page/index

Good luck!